# Pandas dataframe selection df['a'][50][:51]

Tags: pandas, dataframe, selection

I have a dataframe where one of the column name is 'a'

I came across a following selection expression

dataframe['a'][50][:50]

I understand dataframe['a'][50] selects the row 49 in column ['a'], but what does [:50] do?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If `dataframe['a'][50][:50]` doesn't error out and it actually returns something, it means `the row 49 in column ['a']` contains iterables(*more precisely sequence types*) such as `list`, `string`, `tuple`...

`dataframe['a'][50][:50]` returns the sequence from element `0` to `49` from the value of `the row 49 in column ['a']`.

As I said above, if `the row 49 in column ['a']` doesn't contain a sequence type, you will get errors. Try check `dataframe['a'][50]` to see if it is a sequence type

---

Note: `dataframe['a'][50]` is chain-indexing. It is not recommended. However, it is out of the scope of this question so I don't go into the detail of it.

Comment: Thank you! It actually contains string, so it selected character from 0 to 49

Comment: Chain-indexing is not recommended then methods like .loc[] or .iloc[] would be the choice

Comment: @user3562812: you are welcome. it makes sense. On chain-indexing, yes, it is recommended using `.loc` and `.iloc` :)